# CSS flipping page "trembles"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a flipping page effect with pure CSS. I found [this code](http://cssdeck.com/labs/pure-css3-page-flip-effect) and now I'm trying to customize it. Basically I want the flipping animation to happen once the page is loaded. So I did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/373uca9q/). Now instead of `#page-flip:hover #s3` (for example) I have `.hover #s3` and I add `hover` class to `#page-flip` with JS:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
function init(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('page-flip').classList.add('hover')
    }, 100);
}
```

It works just fine. The problem is, on both animations I see a little page "trembling" when the animation starts. I'm trying to get rid of it for hours and for now no luck. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: that happens with the source code too. try hover multiple times, you will see the effect.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, that's why I wrote that I see that "tremble" on both animations. But I still can't get rid of...